# What does "you’ve got cars on the brain" mean?

Tags: meaning, idioms

I was chatting with someone today and the person wrote this sentence, but I don't get the meaning of it under the context.

A: I will be a little late today. My car does not start.

B: You’ve got cars on the brain.

What is B saying in this context??

Comment: [have something on the brain](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+on+the+brain) -  (informal)
to not be able to stop thinking or talking about one particular thing. As it happens, their example usage is *You've got cars on the brain. Can't we talk about something else for a change?*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### [Have on the brain](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/have+on+the+brain)

It means being unable to stop thinking or talking about one particular thing.

From your example, I just think that B is [having a play on words](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/a+play+on+words) and nothing more.

Comment: Hello, NVZ. The question is general reference, as FF indicates by answering in a 'comment'.

Comment: Hi, NVZ. I admire your enthusiasm and willingness to help English learners. But as Edwin mentioned, this question is easily answerable by Googling the phrase. Just a heads-up. (1) See if the question is too easy. (2) See if the question received any downvote (It received two). (3) See if the question might be better suited at our sister site,[English Language Learners](http://ell.stackexchange.com/). Those questions are off-topic and we are discouraging answering those questions. You will learn more as time goes by. And try to understand what kind of question is being closed and why. Good luck

Comment: @Rathony Agreed. Thank you. :) IMD, there wasn't a comment, nor downvote when I answered it.